# Removing shaded area title from the graph in Stata

Tags: graph, stata

I built this graph but unable to remove/rename the label of the shaded area. How to do both?

[image]

```
line smunits timenew if maxcumul==158453||area smunits timenew if  timenew < 16.3&maxcumul==158453, legend(label(1 "Actual unit sales")) area("Weekly Sales") ytitle("Weekly Sales") xtitle("Week") title("All Oxi-Active, unit sales")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For renaming the shaded area, have you tried this?

```
line smunits timenew if maxcumul==158453||area smunits timenew if  timenew < 16.3&maxcumul==158453, legend(label(1 "Actual unit sales")  label(2 “Name Here”)) area("Weekly Sales") ytitle("Weekly Sales") xtitle("Week") title("All Oxi-Active, unit sales")
```

i.e. add `label(2 “Name Here”)`

Comment: instead of writing the whole code in one line, could you please write it on many lines.